# What is Skinn & Sheer in the Ambrose Bierce fable: The Rainmaker?

Tags: american-english, speech, literature, north-american-english, money

In the tale of Ambrose Bierce - The Rainmaker it is said the following:

> hat is a pretty good joke," said the Reporter, laughing as well as he could in the strangling rain - "a mule driver's prayer answered!"

And the response is this:

> "Child of levity and scoffing," replied the other; "you err again, misled by these humble habiliments. I am the Rev. Ezekiel Thrifft, a minister of the gospel, now in the service of the great manufacturing **firm of Skinn & Sheer**. They make balloons, kites, dynamite bombs, and electrical apparatus."

I do not know if Skinn or Sheer has an individual meaning as well as mixed up together but I understand that sometimes in english a family company is named Arthur&Mark for example but I do not what has in common this beauty products with the fabrication of Dynamite.

So If you know or can help me out with that word I would pretty grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: The *firm of Skinn & Sheer* is a made-up name, and has a breezy feeling like the *Rev. Ezekial Thrifft.* I don't think there's a special meaning implied.

Comment: An enquiry about a made-up name rather than about standard usages.

Answer (score 4):

Ambrose Bierce was given to using names with symbolic meaning. The "Rev. Ezekiel Thrifft" uses *thrift* to suggest how the reverend wishes to present himself: as someone who is virtuous in the handling of money.

For **Skinn & Sheer** read "skin and shear" and you will get some idea of what he wants to suggest: that this company will brutally divest their customers from whatever possessions and funds they have, the way cattle are skinned and sheep are shorn.